# Use paint bucket in empty layer in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

I want to use paint bucket for a layer. But I do not want to change base layer. Instead I want the color added by paint bucket to different empty layer. How can I do that?

Comment: Just make a empty layer and apply paintbucket. But the tip is to learn to never to use it instead learn to use selections and fill them

Comment: or, actually, use a Solid Color layer. That has the advantage of filling the whole canvas and it's easy to change the color if you change your mind.

Answer (score 1):

You must add a new layer first. The Paint Bucket tool will **never** create a new layer on it's own.

Comment: I know. But how do I add the color(created by paint bucket) to the new layer?

Comment: The Paint bucket simply fills. If you want the fill on a new layer, create a new layer, then define the area the paint bucket should fill, then click it with the paint bucket. Frankly, the Paint Bucket is a very rudimentary tool that doesn't offer any real control.